# Running asp classic page in ASP.NET application using oracle database

Tags: asp.net, oracle, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I am trying to debug one application which has mostly .aspx and .cs pages and the database behind it is an oracle SQL Developer database.
The whole application runs fine but it crashes on launching pages with .asp extension.
Below is the error:

"*ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a' 
Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.*

After Googling I did enable ASP checkbox in Windows ADD/remove features.
Also, I tried changing Pipeline to classic and enabled 32-bit mode in the application pool of IIS server, but then the whole application stopped running in Visual Studio.
I had also created an odbc DNS driver in ODBCAD32.

Everything works fine but only crashes with .asp pages.

Comment: That is not your problem, ASP is working. How do I know this?, because the VBScript engine is reporting an error from ADODB *(which both run inside Classic ASP)*. The specific issue is related to the provider you are trying to use in your connection string to talk to some data source, it's pretty clear this particular server doesn't have it installed, so install it.

Comment: I did no understand the 'whole application stopped running in Visual Studio'. Are you working on a asp classic or asp.net application?

Comment: @RicardoPontual you can run Classic ASP via IIS Express or a local copy of IIS in Visual Studio. Plus the OP already mentioned they are using both.

Comment: @Lankymart , I am new to Oracle Database. But I can tell you that this error comes only when I am locally running application while debugging, the same application runs perfectly with the exactly same connection string in the Test Server, where the application is published. I have installed Oracle 12 c. The connection string is in WEB.CONFIG file: 
 "<add key="DSN" value="Data Source=gdwt;User Id=rdet;Password=********" />" 
What server I must install? I think I did not understand your point?

Comment: The point is this you are getting a provider error, your provider is Oracle so the Oracle driver is not registered as a provider for your DSN. Now this can happen for multiple reasons but the most common is architecture mismatch. If you have a 64 bit system, is Oracle installed 64 or 32 bit? The architectures have to match, so if it's 32 bit Oracle for example then the Web Application also has to be running in 32 bit to find the Oracle provider. If it's a 64 bit system and you added the DSN to the default ODBCAD32.exe that also might be the issue if the Web Application is looking at 32 bit.

Comment: My system is 64 bit and I have installed 64 bit oracle 12 c. i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all, ADODB cannot open database given in the connection string. Typically, classic asp must have the connection string somewhere in its code and it does not read the web.config file, which is for asp.net. To troubleshoot, open the source code of the failed asp page, find where it calls database, and check the connection string. It might happen that asp used "includes" and the connection string was defined in a different file, specified in `<!--#include file="..."-->`

Examples of connection string to Oracle can be seen [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300382).

Comment: your clue did help me a lot :-), in connection string I used  "driver = {Oracle in OraClient12Home1}" then it worked!!!! Rest part of the connection string is still the same. Many thanks for resolving my first question in StackOverFlow.